# Divs layout when using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make two divs side by side like this shown in the picture below.
[I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QMfQ.png)

However, the when the screen's width becomes larger, the layout becomes this:
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGUuu.png)
Here is the code: 
 Is there any master who can help me through this?
    Thank you so much and appreciate it.

```css
  .Frank-row
        {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }
        
        .Frank-left
        {
            border: 2px dotted red;
        }
        
        .Frank-right
        {
            border: 2px dotted orange;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 Frank-row" >
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 Frank-left" >
                    <p>left</p>
                    <p>left</p>
                    <p>left</p>
                    <p>left</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-offset-sm-6 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-offset-6 Frank-right" >
                    <p>right</p>
                    <p>right</p>
                    <p>right</p>
                    <p>right</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

couple of issues here. First, you don't need the wrapper div to achieve this layout.

Secondly, you had `offset` classes on your div which would push it onto the next line. Removing these classes has fixed the layout.

See example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLVYRg)

Comment: this does not seem to put the two boxes next to each other, ever? https://jsfiddle.net/k7o2af0u/

Comment: @Happysmithers you haven't added bootstrap as a resource. please see my included example

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the col-offset part!

```css
.Frank-row {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.Frank-left {
  border: 2px dotted red;
}

.Frank-right {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 Frank-left">
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 Frank-right">
      <p>right</p>
      <p>right</p>
      <p>right</p>
      <p>right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle to test resizing:
https://jsfiddle.net/xt41kj6j/

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap.css in your file, and remove col-xs-12 in two divs inside Frank-row div, Because `col-xs-12` class takes priority over the other col-** class css values.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 Frank-left">
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 Frank-right">
      <p>right</p>
      <p>right</p>
      <p>right</p>
      <p>right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```